# .htaccess not allowing $_GET to work

Tags: php, .htaccess

My .htaccess file is currently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^display/([0-9]+) display.php?id=$1
```

However, in display.php when I try to access the value for `$_GET['id']`, PHP says there is no value.

Currently `display.php?id=1` works fine but `display/1` doesn't work. I have also tried to see if `display/id=1` or `display.php/1` work but none do.

I'm new to .htaccess, so I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried adding [QSA,L] to the end?   QSA stands for Query String Append. And the L tells it to stop any following rules as long as the rule gets triggered. RewriteRule ... [QLA]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just  need add "QueryString Append" option, it :

```
 RewriteRule ^display/([0-9]+) display.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and if it doesn't work try :

```
 RewriteEngine on
 Options -MultiViews
 RewriteRule ^display/([0-9]+) display.php?id=$1 [L]
```

just for your info :

The `QSA` flag means to append an existing query string *after* the URI has been rewritten. Example:

URL=`http://example.com/foo/bar?q=blah`

Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /index.php?b=$1
```

Result=`/index.php?b=bar`

Notice how the `q=blah` is gone. Because the existing query string is dropped in favor of the one in the rule's target, (b=$1). Now if you include a `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*)$ /index.php?b=$1 [QSA]
```

The result becomes=`/index.php?b=bar&q=blah`

### .htaccess flag list

- C (chained with next rule)
- CO=cookie (set specified cookie)
- E=var:value (set environment variable var to value)
- F (forbidden - sends a 403 header to the user)
- G (gone - no longer exists)
- H=handler (set handler)
- **L (last - stop processing rules)**

> Last rule: instructs the server to stop rewriting after the preceding directive is processed.

- N (next - continue processing rules)
- NC (case insensitive)
- NE (do not escape special URL characters in output)
- NS (ignore this rule if the request is a subrequest)
- P (proxy - i.e., apache should grab the remote content specified in the substitution section and return it)
- PT (pass through - use when processing URLs with additional handlers, e.g., mod_alias)
- R (temporary redirect to new URL)
- R=301 (permanent redirect to new URL)
- QSA (append query string from request to substituted URL)
- S=x (skip next x rules)
- T=mime-type (force specified mime type)

for more information take a look at [RewriteRule Flags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

Comment: QSA is used to combine new and old query strings. Since `id` perameter is already in the rewrite destination there is no need to use QSA

Comment: @starkeen thanks for your comment, you right, but it does not cause any problem here

Comment: still doesn't work I think I'm doing something wrong. It is saying file not found for the second code snippet